# fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in c://

Tags: php, file, fwrite, fputs

I am using latest version of php.. and i stuck on this error

> Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in c:\ this error shows me 6 times
>
> Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in  // this error reapeat only one time.

I am trying to get last id  of last line but i am facing that error.. here is my php code :

```
<?php
include_once('../../fucrenzione.php');
/*
$codeAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$codeAlphabet.= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
$codeAlphabet.= "0123456789";*/
$filename ="data.txt" or die("Unable to open file!");
$line="";
fopen($filename, 'a+');
    for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++ ){

        $va=rand(1,20);
        $re= rand(2,50);
        $data = [
                'val1' => $va,
                'val2' => $re, 
                'body' => getToken(10),
                'Id'=> $i,
                'timestamp' => time()
                ];

     /* echo   "<pre>".*/$line = serialize($data);
     $line .= "\n";
    fwrite($filename, $line);

    }
fclose($filename);
?>
```

I tried to use also `fputs()` but i still get that error.

Comment: Read manuals once again. It's easy. There's even an example.

Comment: can not find.. i am learning php.. sir

Comment: Go to http://php.net - this is the official documentation, and it is pretty awesome most of the time. There is a search box which allows you to search for functions like "fwrite". Go to that page (or use the shortcut: type "http://php.net/fwrite" to go directly to the page, or get a search result page with matching, but different functions if you misspelled something). Use the power of the documentation!

Answer (score 5):

The error tells you the issue. `fopen()` returns a resource:

```
$handle = fopen($filename, 'a+');
```

Then `fwrite()` expects the first argument to be that resource:

```
fwrite($handle, $line);
```

Also, I think the `or die("Unable to open file!");` would be better on the `fopen()` line rather than the assignment line.

Comment: It is such an easy question, and you didn't bother copy&pasting the error message into a search engine and read the results - why should this not be downvoted? A downvote says: This question does not show any research effort...  - which is in fact the case here.

Comment: i searched i couldnot find anything i did nt think about handle sry

Comment: can u tell me also how can i get last line ?